# Font Rendering / Line-Height Issue on Mac/PC (outside of element)

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css, css-tables

## The Design

The info widgets content should be vertically aligned in the middle as such:

[image: Original PSD Design]

---

## The Coded Design

#### Windows: Chrome 20 / FF 14 / IE 9

[image: Windows Coded Design]

#### Mac (Lion / Mt. Lion): Chrome / FF

[image: Mac Coded Design]

---

## The Code

#### HTML

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="weather display clearfix">
        <div class="icon"><img src="imgs/icons/thunderstorms.png" align="Thunderstorms" /></div>

        <div class="fl">
            <p class="temperature">82&deg; / 89&deg;</p>
            <p class="conditions">Thunderstorms</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time display">
        <p>11:59 <span>AM</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="date display clearfix">
        <p class="number fl">23</p>
        <p class="month-day fl">Jun <br />Sat</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- //.info -->
```

#### CSS

```
.info {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:20px 0;
    margin-right:-20px;
    padding:6px 0 0;
}
    .display {
        background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        border-radius:10px;
        -ms-border-radius:10px;
        color:#fff;
        font-family:"Cutive", Arial, sans-serif;
        display:table-cell;
        height:70px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding:3px 15px 0;
    }
        .display p {padding:0;line-height:1em;}
        .time, .date {padding-top:5px;}
            .time p, .date .number {font-size:35px;}
            .time span, .display .month-day, .conditions {
                font-size:14px;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                font-family:"Maven Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
                line-height:1.15em;
                font-weight:500;
            }
            .display .month-day {padding-left:5px;}
            .icon {float:left;padding:0 12px 0 0}
            .display .temperature {font-size:24px;padding:4px 0 0;}
            .display .conditions {text-transform:none;padding:2px 0 0;}
    .lt-ie9 .display { /* IE rgba Fallback */
        background:transparent;
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#20ffffff,endColorstr=#20ffffff);
        zoom:1;
    }
```

---

## The Issue

Looking at the above images of the coded design you can see how the appears to throw off the alignment. Upon further viewing, the text is being rendered outside of the element on the mac.

#### Windows

[image: Windows Coded Design Alignment]

#### Mac

[image: Mac Coded Design Alignment]

---

## Note

I am embedding the fonts through a Google Web Fonts stylesheet.

---

## Tested

I have tried the following:

- Set line-heights on every element.
- Set font-weights on every element.
- Set heights on every element.
- A combination of height/padding-top on every element.
- Used percentages/em/px for padding.

It seems that no matter what I try, the content will never center align perfectly across mac and pc.

---

## My Question(s)

It is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do in a simplistic manner?

Should I forgo the `display:table-cell;` route and set specific heights/paddings on each element and child? I will still run into padding/spacing issues between the two OS's.

What should I categorize this issue under? Line-height? Table-cells? OS? etc...

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? And if so, what are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using a CSS reset and it's custom, but it's not like normalize css.

Comment: Cant believe there's not more on this issue online

Comment: I read somewhere the vertical spacing can be modified with FontForge, if someone knows how to fix this with FontForge would be a golden answer.

Comment: For a FontForge answer see my answer below

Comment: I think `line-height: initial;` will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If it is resolved by using a different font (Arial) then the issue is with the font, not with the CSS. As you have noticed font rendering differs between browsers.

One possible solution could be to download the Cutive font (I see it has a SIL license) and then run it through the Font Squirrel font-face generator. In "Expert" mode there is an option to "Fix Vertical Metrics" which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: This seems to be the only recommendation around to fix this, I've tested this with 4 fonts, they didn't get fixed. So I believe this might work few times.

Comment: thanks for "Font Squirrel font-face generator" tip - that did it!

Comment: Thank you! Fixing Vertical Metrics just saved me hours of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: In my experience (having worked as a print designer for a while) free fonts tend to lack attention to detail like this. Free fonts tend to be more close to just a set of alpha numeric characters, whereas a paid font will have a number of additional features such as kerning, ligatures, etc. It's important to examine any free font before assuming it's going to be bulletproof in production.

Comment: Sadly, Font Squirrel said my font was blacklisted (I have no idea why seeing as I bought it legally) so I used the 'fix vertical metrics' option on transfonter.org instead. Worked a treat! Cheers

Comment: I appreciate this answer (esp because so many people already upvoted it, which was encouraging to see), but I found that it was easier to download FontForge for free and adjust my woff font til it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425906/470749

Answer (score 12):

I think using this website https://transfonter.org/ will save your time instead of downloading FontForg program, upload your fonts and toggle "Fix vertical metrics"
then click convert, it will give you a downloadable zip folder with all types you selected
[image]

Comment: Awesome, you saved my day

Comment: That is a great tool, I must say

Answer (score 10):

I came across this problem with a custom font that had been created for a client's brand. I opened the TTF font in Font Forge. The way I created uniformity with rendering was to adjust the values in Element->Font Info->OS/2->Metrics.

Win Ascent/Descent values appear to work differently to the other values. I had the following values:

`Win Ascent: 1000`

`Win Descent: 0`

`Typo Ascent: 750`

`Typo Descent: -250`

`HHead Ascent: 750`

`HHead Descent: -250`

I changed the Win Ascent and Descent values to:

`Win Ascent: 750`

`Win Descent: 250` (notice the positive value)

It appears you need to match the values except in my case I needed to invert the value of Win Descent to a positive one.

I have very limited knowledge about fonts but this did fix my problem. I generated the font as TTF and then ran it through a web font generator. The fonts now render identically on Mac/Windows 7/Android/iOS.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me when trying to use Gill Sans familly font in browsers running on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

For those who can't use Font Squirrel, I can confirm that this problem could be fixed in Font Forge for the font I was working with. Based on the answer provided by Luke, here are the steps I followed (no new information here, just providing easy-to-follow instructions):

1) Install FontForge (free)
Download from:
https://fontforge.github.io/

2) Open the problematic font in FontForge

3) Choose Element > Font Info
[image]

4) On the left panel, click OS/2, then click the Metrics tab

5) Change Win Ascent to the same number as HHead Ascent, and Win Descent to the POSITIVE value of HHead Descent (i.e., remove minus sign), then click OK. (If those numbers don't address the problem, try adjusting them until you find numbers that fix the issue for your specific font.) 
[image]

6) Click File > Generate Fonts. Choose the font type for your font. If the font is an .otf font, choose OpenType (CFF). Uncheck "Validate Before Saving". Set a name for your new font file. Click Generate.
[image]

Thanks to everyone who contributed answers to this question!

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me having the issue with MacOS rendering the font different than Win-based systems, whereas line-height settings only change the outer height of the fonts letters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One difference for me though, I am addressing this issue for a Chinese font and two steps has to be done differently: In (3) instead of Element > Font Info, go to CID > CID Font Info; and in (6) choose OpenType CID format. All other steps are the same

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this (very annoying problem):

- Set all elements to float:left;
- Set explicit line-heights;

*Enjoy a victory over cross-browser/platform css ridiculousness.*

Comment: I really had to add explicit line-height for my base elements (e.g. `button { line-height: 16px; }`) in my global CSS to have the same line-heights for MacOS/Windows even though the same font-family has been used. Why is this the case? Issue happened with Open Sans.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this issue. Luke's answer helped me. I had to adjust the fonts with FontForge using this settings:

[image: FontForge Settings]

Uncheck all "Is offset" checkboxes and also the "Really use Typo metrics" checkbox. I had most problems with Firefox and IE. Playing around with the value of "Win Descent" fixed it for those two browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem may be in the way Windows/Mac OSX renders fonts. Specifically those that are brought in via `@font-face`. Try switching out which font formats are being used.

Comment: I am using Google Web Fonts. If I use Arial, the font is vertically-aligned perfectly. So yes, it is a font-rendering issue. Though, I am not sure if it's a @font-face based issue. I haven't yet tested to see what the render output would look like if the user has the fonts installed on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

I witnessed the same issue, with a custom font (Trade Gothic) served by FastFonts.

Windows did what it should have.  But all other browsers on Linux based machines, Mac, iOS, Android suffered the problem.

My only solution was to match on the user agent, and namespace the body tag with .not-win

Then my styles could override the line-height specific to non-windows devices.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said in your comment to Jordan Brown that using Arial makes the alignment perfect, this is a font issue. It is likely that whoever created your font did not set the Ascent value properly.

If you have the TTF, upload it to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), select the "Expert" option and then keeping all default options. The one that fixes it I believe is "Fix Vertical Metrics." but I had issues when changing the defaults so I recommend keeping them as-is.

Now the font line height renders the same on MAC and PC (it worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by font format history and Windows/Mac wars, there are different ways to compute line height and if they are not synced in the font you use things will go wrong on some systems

You need to fix your font (if the licensing allows it) or switch to one without this problem

Better, not to make your design depend on an exact value here

Answer (score -1):

The Mac correctly displays the lengths below the baseline as belonging to line height. It seems that OS X counts bottom up whereas Windows calculates from the Top.

Since 1em is the width of the capital M of the used font it is usually smaller than the font's overall height.

Have you tried setting the line-height to be the same as the element height? This usually helps solve these kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting line-heights based off the container height, font-size, padding sizes, etc. It's because Mac renders the line-height from the bottom up that I am having this issue.

Comment: Did you Try different vertical aligns? Maybe baseline or top specifically help.