# How do I stop large fonts from going outside a div?

Tags: css

I am working on an online content editor. Everything was working fine and suddenly, large fonts started being cropped at the top of the div. What used to happen was that the actual insert point in the div moved downwards slightly as the font got bigger. Now, it remains fixed as the font gets bigger. Here is the css for the contentDiv.

```
.textObject { 
position:absolute; 
white-space:normal;
overflow:hidden;
}

.textMove {
border:1px transparent dashed;
}

.textMove:hover { 
cursor:move;
border:1px #999999 dashed; 
}
```

The hover class is what is producing the dotted line in this image:

[image]

Clearly, something else in my css somewhere has gone wrong. Can someone help me determine what might cause this? I can trace through with the edit tools, but I have no idea what to look for. I need to know what can cause large fonts to be cropped like this.

BTW, I know that overflow:visible will show the text, but I want it contained inside the box.

Thanks so much for your always-diligent help.

EDIT: Actual CSS form this portion of the code (rendered)

```
<div id="slideHolder59" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<div id="stageLayer59" class="stageLayer" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px; height: 640px;"></div>
<div id="slayer11" class="setObject setMove ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="top: 489px; left: 696px; width: 200px; height: 84px; cursor: move;"></div>
<div id="tlayer65" class="textObject textMove ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="left: 101px; top: 79px; width: 532px; height: 111px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Lato; font-size: 97px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; font-style: normal; text-align: left; opacity: 1; cursor: move;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't clear how are you positioning this element. Please provide us with the DOM and advisable a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The js fiddle won't help because in it's simple form, this works fine. This is a very complex multi-layered slide (think powerpoint for the web) so there is a main window, then a stage, then a slide holder div that contains all of the elements. I've added the actual  css for that portion above...

Comment: If the problem is the font and not the CSS, this free tool helps you fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425906/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think its the absolute positioning you have set. Try some top padding

Comment: I always had the absolute positioning. That is how I can drag it around and save it's coordinates. Padding works, but I can't pad by 50 pixels. And as I said, it used to work with no padding, As the font got bigger I could see the insert point move downwards in the edit div (contentEditable div).

Answer (score 4):

FOUND IT! I had set  global line-height value and was never over-riding it. Whew! Thanks guys.

Comment: Nope. So I accepted another that got me on the right track. :)