# Padding differences in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, padding, vertical-alignment, difference

My buttons appear as they should in Chrome and Firefox but the text fails to vertically center in Internet Explorer. Most times I success in getting around this problem but this time I'm stuck. A little help would be nice!

Here's the adress so you can see for yourself, the problem is within the header meny.:

http://spectra.macework.se

Here's my css:

```
#header-family_menu ul li a{

display:block;
font-size: 1.1em;
color:#000;
font-family:"SofiaProBold";
line-height: 1.3em;
padding: 9.0px 0 3.5px 0;
width:92.5%;
```

as you can see i've been trying to use line-height and padding to center my text but this time it fails in IE.

Comment: are you not missing close bracket }

Comment: no, it's further down. I just pasted what's relevant to the problem

Comment: instead of padding just give `height:1.7em` and make same value for `line-height`; in using  padding for buttons makes this kind of probs

Comment: That worked for IE but then it gets messy in other browsers, so still the same problem.

Comment: After further investigation in VMware (Virtual PC) the problem exist in chrome on PC as well. So the difference is in the OS rather than in the browser.

Comment: I found this thread, and it seems like the problem is found: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element) It seems to be a difference in font rendering across browsers or/and OS's. So what can you do?