# Text is not vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I'm using the line-height property to align some text to icons in a menu. I've created a simplified version (without icons) to illustrate my problem. It seems to be a problem with the general vertical alignment of fonts.

You can see this problem on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/1/

The code is really simple:

```
 <div>qb - Some text - qb</div>
```

An adding a style:

```
 div {
     background-color: green;
     height: 22px;
     line-height: 22px;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
 }
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like]

And this is how it SHOULD look like:

[image: And this is how it SHOULD look like]

Why does this happen in newer browsers? I've tested it on Windows 8.1 64 bit in Firefox 27.0.

EDIT: I want to know, WHY the browsers does not render correctly. A small letter like 'a' should get the same space to the top and bottom of the 'green', when applying a line-height thats as height as the container. But the rendering is wrong.

EDIT#2: It's an issue with the font. Segoe UI seems to have a strange baseline. When using Arial, Verdana or whatever vertical alignment fits better (but it's also not perfect). -> http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/22/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/3/ <--- btw the behavior is perfect, q always flows out and your text is vertically aligned as well

Comment: You would be right, @Mr.Alien I used 15px and looking over it I was 1 out! `:(`

Comment: But setting another line-height to solve to problem cannot be the correct way. It seems so the baseline of Segoe UI is wrong.

Comment: I really want to accept one of the answers, but no one answers the question. I've found the baseline-shift CSS property, which seems to be in draft state. http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/baseline-shift.php

Comment: If the problem is the font and not the CSS, this free tool helps you fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425906/470749

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem with a paid font. After a bit research, I found this tool → https://transfonter.org/ . Just, upload your fonts, and don’t forget to change to “on” the option “Fix vertical metrics”. After this download the new fonts and replace them with your previous ones. Worked for me :)

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution. But I wonder how some fonts, even premium ones, are not centered correctly. This can't be mistakenly, there must be a reason!?!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Font ist now center aligned. Nice!

Comment: I knew about this tool, but I didn't know that it can fix vertical metrics, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I know I might be a little late, but better late than never. Yes you're right - it's an issue with your font, in your case the *ascender*.

To fix this you need to change your typo's ascender (in some other cases descender).

**One solution Mac Users:**
"To edit these in the font you will need to download the [Apple Font Tool Suite](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/). Once you’ve installed this you need to open Terminal and navigate to the directory that contains your font. After that enter the following command:

> ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf

This will create a file called font.hhea.xml, open this new file into a text editor and adjust the values for ascender and descender. Generally if you font sits too low you want to decrease ascender and increase descender. After editing and saving enter the following command into terminal to reconstruct your Font file:

> ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf

You can now use the font.ttf file in your application. If the font still isn’t right just repeat the above procedure until you are happy." *- Source: Andy Yardley*

Answer (score 4):

Each browser support different type of file format because of this sometimes browsers are not able to render the font properties as expected and line-height issue occurs.

For paid fonts always add all the font extension files to your fonts/vendors folder and use the below format to add fonts in your stylesheet.

**font-face format:**

```
       @font-face {
         font-family: 'MyWeb';
         src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
         src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

For more details you can refer below link:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16850111)

Comment: Thanks for guiding me here, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/6/)

Remember if you are setting a fixed height, and also adjusting the font size, line height, then its bound to be messy. You either make it a float and remove the height and let it occupy as much height as it needs or manually set a larger height, but still the different techniques of rendering used b different browsers would make it difficult for you to maintain same look cross browser. so I suggest the method I used in the JSFiddle..

you may then compensate for the difference by applying a padding.

```
padding-bottom: 5px;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, this is just a comment (I can't comment, because my reputation is not enough).

Year passed, but the problem is still here... Hope, we will find an answer someday.

I've tried to investigate this a little. Here is jsfiddle with updated original question: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqzwh9/).

I've added 4 horizontal lines to understand the font dimensions: top, middle, bottom, baseline:

```css
div {
  background-color: #9F9;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
span.mid {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
span.bot {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
span.base {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  qb - Some text - qb
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="mid"></span>
  <span class="bot"></span>
  <span class="base"></span>
</div>
```

As a result we can see the difference between Chrome/Win10 and FireFox/Ubuntu:
[image: example of baseline]

In Ubuntu I have baseline (and middle line) for some fonts 1px higher than on Windows.

Looking to other answers (and using my experience), I can say:

- `padding` will not help
- `vertical-align:middle` will not help
- changing original `div` to `display:flex;justify-content:center` (having inner text wrapped in `span` or `div`) will not help
- changing original `div` to `display:table` (having inner text wrapped in `display:table-cell`) will not help
- changing outer `div` to `span` will not help
- `box-sizing` will not help

All the options above I've checked and they do not work: we always have text 1px higher in Ubuntu, than on Windows.

Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add/change a `line-height`.

To get the `q` and `b` in the middle, use `line-height:16px;` however the `some text` will look dodgy. Mess around with the `16px;` and you might find what you want.

Example:

```
div{
    line-height:16px;
}
```

Comment: That will cause other unintended consequences, like the total height of the text to increase or decrease, potentially pushing up and down other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text portion into another `<div>` and can try `display:table` and `display:table-cell` approach with `verical-align:middle`

Though this is different from your requirement but i think you should practice this way:

*Remove line-height completely from the parent*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"><div class="content">qb - Some text - qb</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color: green;
    height: 55px;
    display:table; // here it is
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}
.content{
    display:table-cell; // here it is
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/11/)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this. The text is not correctly centered vertically in a table-cell at all (I checked the pixels over and under the text). There is always differcne of 4 or 5 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

div is the wrong element for you in this case.. Just try this one and compare:

```
span {
    background-color: green;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}

div {
    background-color: green;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}
```

And

```
<span>qb - Some text - qb|ÜÄÖ</span>
<br><br>
<div>qb - Some text - qb|ÜÄÖ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers act normal. You may be confused because your font size, 20px is smaller than your line height, 22px and it seems like it is going to fit in. But it won't.

As an example, setting a H1's font-size to 24px would produce a line-height of 39px. 12px font-size would result in an 18px line-height.

Comment: I just used a line-height smaller than the font-size to illustrate the problem. The margin between small letters like 'a' should be the same (or near the same) to the top and bottom border of the 'green', but it is not.

Comment: What are the actual sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to your code.

Example:

```
div {
     background-color: green;
     height: 22px;
     line-height: 22px;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
     padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not vertically centered at all: http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/20/ - You see the different distance at top and bottom.

Comment: Well if you can not get it in the center by default, try tweaking the code a bit [http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/21/]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you are looking for: 
http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/19/

You need to add below line to your CSS.

```
 padding-bottom:5px;
```

However that is not the way line height "should" be working. To my knowledge the bottom of letters like p and q is not considered into the median height value of the font. You would have to measure against a capital letter to get a fairly accurate result.

You don't need div height by the way, unless it matters to you what height the element will be on the outside.

I'd suggest you look into "box-sizing" too. To prevent padded element from expanding outside dimensions.

Also, using old browsers as a measure of right and wrong ways to do things is probably not the safest approach to coming to any CSS related conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, I tried to fix the font but I couldn't do it automatically.
I ended up having a set up like this -

```
<div style="height:someHeight">
 <div style="font-size:someHeight">
  Text Text Text Text
 </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly for me as the excess padding as at the bottom

Answer (score -1):

You apply specific height to div and line-height .. you don't need any of that to center vertical a text.

```
div {
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/2/

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KFxG3/16/

You need to remove the height element. the div calculates the height according to the font size.

css

```
div{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
}
```

Comment: A good thing you can see at this code, that the text is not centered vertically when no height and line-height is given. May be it's an issue with the font?!

Comment: O yes that can be the case.

Answer (score -1):

This is like 4 years late, but sometimes you have to check if the box-sizing is correct.

```
a{
  box-sizing: content-box
}
```

Then your line-height and height should center the text.

Answer (score -2):

```
vertical-align: middle;
padding-bottom:5px;
```

you  have to add in  your css

Comment: This doesn't do anything to OP's code (in terms of looks).

Comment: give padding-bottom:5px;

Comment: Please explain your solution so that future visitors to this question will understand how this solves the problem at hand.