# Why is Spartan font not centered vertically?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to figure out why my font is not being vertically aligned. I'm using **Spartan MB** font provided by Google and it's just not looking right, [see here](https://codepen.io/comatory/pen/rNWVZVg).

[image: Spartan MB font used in HTML button and HTML input]

My HTML markup is this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      button, input {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <input type="text" value="Hello world" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Why using regular **Arial** font has no issue whatsoever?

Approaches I have tried

1. Setting different `line-heigh` properties. Does not help.
2. Setting `vertical-align: text-bottom` does not help.
3. Modifying the font itself using `ftxdumperfuser` utility as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580059/text-is-not-vertically-centered/56812521#56812521) by changing ascender and descender attirbutes. That helped a bit but only worked in Chromium browsers.

Could someone enlighten me on this behaviour? Is there a cross-browser way to fix this?

Comment: If you also use letters that  go *under* the baseline (like y, p, g etc.) you'll see that it *is* filling the height  and therefore centered. Alignment won't change according to the letters used, so it has to work for all letters at once.

Comment: @Johannes that is interesting and I see that technically, it just has to fit the font. But to me from aesthetic point of view it seems off, would not you say?

So I guess it's up to the human to compensate for this. It would be nice if fonts could set their "center" and browser could pick up on it somehow.

Comment: well, but "their center" would differ between your example "Click me" and for example "Type something" - the y and the g in there have descenders, "Click here" doesn't and therefore seems more off-center. So where is the "center of the font": Different for both examples? If yes, that would require (automatic) different treatment depending on the text content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is by the font its self, how its rendered. You can only work with different padding from top/bottom.

```css
  button, input {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  }
  
 .trick {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <button class="trick">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Input also fixed**

```css
button, input {
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
  
  input {
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button><span style="vertical-align: sub;">Click me</span></button>
    <input type="text" value="Hello world" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I wonder why most of the fonts work fine and this one does not. 
Also it seems to be not only issue in button but in text inputs as well.

Comment: its as Johannes explained. You can see it when you mark the text in the input. A small hack for the input i explained in a comment under kuznetsovs comment. `button, input {font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;vertical-align: middle;} input {padding-top: 4px;}` should fix it visual.

Comment: It still depends on the text content (see my last comment to the question), so actually you have to always adjust the padding values depending on the text (i.e. if it contains letter with descenders or not)