# Some fonts on apple devices has more padding than Windows font

Tags: css, fonts

I seen this error some days ago in other project with a Trajan Pro font, and now I encounter it again.

[image: Font seen on Apple devices]
[image: Font seen on Windows devices]

As you can see on Windows (second image) the font is beeing vertical aligned ( just put a background-color for it ). On the apple devices the font doesnt have any padding-top, just a lot of padding-bottom. I see that the problem appears when the font is uppercase. When is lowercase it looks ok, have the same padding top and bottom.

Can i fix this font issue by using css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the answer here:

[Font Rendering / Line-Height Issue on Mac/PC (outside of element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element)

Because of the font rendering problems between operating systems, we can use a tool that is called [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) where we must upload our font and it will have the option to "Fix Vertical Metrics". After i've done this, the font looks ok on Apple devices also. Although i noticed some pixels changed in the font ... but i`m happy that now works on all operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers render fonts differently. This includes Windows/Mac versions of the 'same' browsers, AFAIK.

Have you tried explicitly declaring line-heights for the element in question?

Comment: yes, this is not a problem of line-height... This is just a problem of font rendering. The font on the Apple has no padding-top ...

Comment: Is the font Trajan Pro? I'm finding literally nothing on Google about 'Trojan Pro'. If it's Trajan, [it seems like this is a known issue](https://forums.adobe.com/message/6109468) -- it was designed for large sizes + won't render properly at small sizes.

If this is some free font that is called 'Trojan Pro', that might be your problem right there, and it might not be easily fixed -- free fonts are frequently (not always!) a you-get-what-you-pay-for thing.

Comment: Yes - they often render differently, there can be changes in weight (boldness), anti-aliasing and a whole slew of other aspects relating to the font. Of course different browsers will also render the fonts differently and a font may get substituted for another one entirely when used on a different OS. It all depends on the intended design use of the font and the quality / effort put into the font definition.