# Mac / win different font vertical position

Tags: css, fonts, cross-platform, vertical-alignment

I have very simple element on page - it's a quantity balloon for basket, which I'm unable to set properly. Not only the font is dramatically different, but its vertical position differs significantly for a small element like this:

[image]

I've tried some solutions from stackoverflow (e.g. to set line-height -1 from font size), but no luck. Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="basket-qty">6</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.basket-qty {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C1637D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e563tgdn/

Answer (score 0):

Could it "just" be Font Rendering? Do css-setting like this help to normalize?

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
text-size-adjust: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

Comment: Your fix resolves only font weight, not vertical position issue, which is more significant in my case. I've posted a JSFiddle link at the end of my question, you can try it yourself.

Comment: @Martin yeh, the answer was a shot in the dark, but it looks better that way :) you can try to display with "display: inline-table;" and also check this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element