# Text not vertically centered in line

Tags: css, alignment

The text seems to have more space under than above.

How can I fix this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: did you tried line-height? post relevant html css code what you tried sofar

Comment: if the text is 20px and the container (a div or something similar) is forced to 30 (for example) it will be aligned to top-left as default. Other property that may cause this is padding or margin. Check your text have no padding or margin

Comment: You cannot. It's in the font you use. Depending on what you want to achieve, you could add a padding-top to the element.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: @connexo I can add padding top but what happens if the font is changed.

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm any solutions, yet? Or is it just depending on the font you are using? Could you answer your question, or maybe just drop a reply?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is `no specific padding/ margin` in your text. Then, give a `proper line-height` to the text, till you get it vertically centered. You can try `google's developer tool`( right click on the element and do inspect element or simply press F12 ) for checking proper line-height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's what I'm doing. As you can see from the screenshot, the highlight box is not including padding (which is green) and margin (which is orange)

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm did you try adjusting the `line-height` ?

Comment: I did. the space above and below the text are not equal. I think that's the font issue. not css

Comment: F12 only works on Windows afaik. On Mac it is CMD-ALT-i.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the combination of font and browser you are using. I had the same issue, and I fixed it by running the font file through **FontSquirrel's** **Webfont Generator** at https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. In the generator settings, make sure that **Vertical Metrics** is set to *Auto-Adjust Vertical Metrics*.

I discovered this fix from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860322/3163495

[image]