# How to vertically align lower case text in mobile safari?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

With a div that has

```
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
```

I get these results:

[image]
[image]

what css can I use to make it v-align the text to middle regardless of its case?

Comment: share your entire code ( css html ) not just a picture. there are a number of ways to v-align a text

Comment: the code I included is covering the technique

Comment: it's not covering anything. make a working example of your problem so we can help you better. otherwise we can just guess what the problem is

Comment: the technique of setting the same line-height as height to vertically align the text, ever heard about it?
https://jsfiddle.net/gz4maerq/  
http://imgur.com/a/jC79a

Comment: The fiddle does not produce the screenshot.

Comment: because as the title and tags say it is specific to mobile safari

Comment: 'ever heard about it ?' . good luck getting an answer

Comment: so now that I showed you the jsfiddle what is it that I didn't include in the description that you insisted I share the entire code and said my code didn't cover anything and said that there're "a number of ways to v-align a text"? like it wasn't clear what way this one is using.

Comment: what's your font family i recommend use google font if you can also use default line height 1.4 or 1.42857143

Comment: also see this answer as well this might help you more http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860322/2724173

Comment: one time-proven technique that works in basically all browsers is `text-transform: uppercase;` :)

Comment: 500 point bounty, down-voted into oblivion. Ruthless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use `table-cell` display, which is compatible in most of the browsers versions.

You then just need to use `text-align` and `vertical-align` to make it perfectly centered.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 3rem;
}

span {
    background-color: #4900CE;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 500px;
    padding: 1rem;
    min-width: 2.5rem;
    
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>ONE</span>
<br>
<span>one</span>
```

I've went ahead and tested this code in most of the iOS browsers with Browserstack. You can find all the results [here](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/1eec35f0ab4b07a7e59845970c8a59d2ac46c0fa) (some of their hosts are broken, thus the white shots).

---

You can alternatively use flexbox with something like

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It's easy to v-align text, but the question is how to `v-align the text to middle regardless of its case`. With lower case it doesn't look aligned (just like on screenshots that OP posted)

Comment: +1 for mentioning using flex-box. I've found flex -boxes to be invaluable when v/h-centering stubborn elements.

Comment: flexbox vertical text alignment breaks when mixing different font sizes on the same line

Answer (score 6):

I think your best bet would to be to work with `em` and `ex` here.

I have noticed that uppercase letters seem to be vertically centered by default. Most of the time, they have a height of **around two thirds** of `1em`, while the height of lowercase letters is almost always **exactly** `1ex`.

Knowing these things, you can give the lowercase letters an offset of `calc(((-1em / 1.5) + 1ex) / 2)`, this moves the text up with half the size of the uppercase letters, and down half the size of the lowercase letters.
To be able to do this, you'll have to do some padding trickery, or simply wrap the text into another element, like a `span`.

### Check out [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/b4pew5zg/)

```css
html, body { height: 100% } *, ::before, ::after { position: relative }

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex.sans {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.flex div {
  font-size: 17vh;
  background-color: #40C;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: .25em;
}

@media (max-width: 200vh) { .flex div { font-size: 8.5vw } }

.flex div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - .5px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.flex.centered div:last-child span {
  top: calc(((-1em / 1.5) + 1ex) / 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  Not centered<div><span>ONE</span></div><div><span>one</span></div>
</div>
<div class="flex centered">
  Centered<div><span>ONE</span></div><div><span>one</span></div>
</div>
<div class="flex sans">
  Not centered<div><span>ONE</span></div><div><span>one</span></div>
</div>
<div class="flex centered sans">
  Centered<div><span>ONE</span></div><div><span>one</span></div>
</div>
```

There's a big chance this will work right away. If it doesn't, you can try changing `1.5` to some other value like `1.4` or `1.75`.

Answer (score 2):

See below example:

```css
.capsule{
  border-radius:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 15px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Arial;
}

.capsule>span{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.capsule > i {
    opacity:0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="capsule">
  <span> ONE </span>
  <i> ONE </i>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="capsule">
  <span> one </span>
  <i> one </i>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="capsule">
  <span> TWO </span>
  <i> TWO </i>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="capsule">
  <span> two </span>
  <i> two </i>
</div>
```

This will work on all browsers except IE 8. You can see working example [here](https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/YVaZKx).

Comment: thank you, this is a wonderful approach but it has a downside -- it is only for fixed width divs as the inner content position absolutely won't autoexpect the parent capsule.

Comment: Yes but for widths and heights, you can play with display:inline or display : inline-block and min-width: and min-height properties etc.

Comment: I have found a way. i am updating answer shortly.

Comment: I have updated answer. Now div width and height will increase automatically according to content size, if you remove width and height from CSS. But you will need to add padding: to look text nicer. I have updated codepen as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex:

```css
.badge {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari prefix */
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center; /* Safari prefix */
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari prefix */
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.badge.large {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p>Large badge:</p>
<div class="badge large">
  ONE
</div>

<p>Normal badge:</p>
<div class="badge">
  two
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jjb09f9/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. The problem is basically font Vertical Metrics which is actually issue.

I recommend use google font if you can if not than,

- Go to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

**Note:** Do not use blacklisted font. If you want, go for license.

- Upload the font you want to use;
- choose “EXPERT…”
- Select **EOT Lite** if you require IE support;
- In Rendering section, check **“Fix Vertical Metrics”**; **(This is Important)**
- This will fix Vertical Metrics which will fix your `line-height` issue.

**CSS Recommendation**:

Use default body `line-height` 1.4 or 1.42857143 do not relay on `line-height: normal` because different browser has different default value.

Answer (score 1):

What if your word would have ascenders ( the part of the letters going higher to the letter x like ftlkidhjb ) or descender (like jyqp) then the text will poke out of the edges of your button. That's why it seems not centered. The only solution to make it feel centered is to make the button as high as 2 or 3 times the line height.

Answer (score 0):

To make lower case text aligned you have to offset it manually to compensate for the extra height that would have to be occupied by upper case text, but that would make uppercase text misaligned. You can make your divs look inline or [inline-flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and then you can simply force all text in these badges to be uppercase:

```css
.up div {
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 0.3em 0.7em;
  display: inline; 
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <div>ONE</div> <div>One</div> <div>one</div>
</div>
```

Or lowercase+offset:

```css
.low div {
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.7em 0.4em 0.7em;
  display: inline; 
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="low">
  <div>ONE</div> <div>One</div> <div>one</div>
</div>
```

Here's the output on iPhone 5:

[image: screenshot]