# PC Chrome and Mac Chrome are calculating box height differently

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face, webfonts

The design of the site I'm working on calls for underlines squished right along the bottom of the text, literally touching the baseline. I'm absolute positioning an `after` pseudo element with a border-bottom to accomplish this, and I'm seeing a strange inconsistency between the box height in Mac Chrome and PC Chrome.

Notice the "Visit" link in the top right corner. This screenshot is Mac Chrome and it's how it is supposed to look. The dev tools claim the box height of the `<a>` tag is `30px`.
[image]
[image]

Look what's happening for the same site in PC Chrome. As you can see, there's a small gap below the text and the underline because PC Chrome thinks that same exact element has a box height of `22px`.
[image]

The CSS for the underline:

`a {
        position: relative;
        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 1em;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            border-bottom: 4px solid;
        }
    }`

As you can see, the `1em` that positions the underline lands in a different place on the two different OS's.

### What's going on here!?

Here's a round-up of things I've checked:

- I exported the woff/woff2 files using [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) with the "Match X-Height" option turned on to "100%"
- Both browsers have the zoom set to 100%
- The calculated font-size of the element is 22px on both.
- The calculated line-height of the element is 22px on both.
- Both elements have `box-sizing: content-box`.

Comment: Blind shots: OS zoom level? Default browser font size? VM issue with retina screen compensation?

Comment: Is the computed line-height the same on both operating systems? Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860322/5561605

Comment: @Kaiido The zoom levels are the same and the font-sizes are both calculating to 22px. It's hard for me to rule out the VM issue but this bug was reported to me by a client who wasn't using a VM so it doesn't appear that's the cause. I wish it was that easy :-)

Comment: @sol That answer is actually what inspired me to try re-converting the fonts with FontSquirrel. They don't go into detail but I used the same setting they described and got the same result. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If the box model is truly the issue, you can set the box-sizing attribute on your `a` tag and `::after` element to force consistent rendering of the box-model, then adjust your variables as necessary.

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

Comment: They are both `content-box`.

Comment: Are you able to recreate this in codepen, or some similar editor and post the link