# Font positioning differences in a <span> between Mac and Windows

Tags: html, css, layout, browser

I recently came along a font(-file) that seems to get positioned vastly different inside a span on different operating systems. If someone knowledgeable with fonts knows what exactly is going wrong here and if there is a fix or a workaround for something like this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I've made a pen here: https://codepen.io/jls_chris/pen/rQmpEE
which should show you the basic setup of the element:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="value">24%</span>
  </div>
</div>

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Impact LT Std';
  src: url('https://sorry.font.is.licensed/ImpactLTStd.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.box {
  height: 163px;
  width: 259px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;

  // Set by gsap
  opacity: 1;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

  // For debugging
  background-color: lightblue;

  .wrapper {
    height: calc(163px - 33px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    // For debugging
    background-color: lightgreen;

    .value {
      font-family: 'Impact LT Std', Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 95px;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

      // For debugging
      text-decoration: underline;
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```

As the font license doesn't allow me to share it, here a couple of images:

On Windows (any browser):

[image: Correct Positioning on Windows]

On Mac (any browser):

[image: Wrong Positioning on Mac]

On Windows everything looks correct but on Mac the text is clearly not centered as I would expect it to be.

The span is correctly positioned on both and has the correct dimensions but the it seems like the baseline is positioned completely differently on the two OSes. I tested a couple of other fonts but could not reproduce it.

Does someone know what could be wrong/broken in this font and if there might be a fix?

Comment: It sounds either like a font-rendering problem, or could just be a line height issue. 

Does `.value { line-height: 1; }` fix anything?

Comment: @elveti No, sadly that does not help.

Comment: oh, too bad. Then the problem is probably with the font itself. You can try the solutions mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element
especially the FontSquirrel WebfontGenerator has helped me with similar cases in the past. Squirrel converts your .otf font into all other types (ttf, woff) to make it as crossbrowser compatible as possible. But they blacklist licensed fonts, so I don't know if it works for you. Sorry I couldn't help you with a simpler/better solution

Comment: @elveti Oh that issue does look very, very similar. Sadly the font is blacklisted on FontSquirrel so I will have to see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elveti linked the following post (in a comment, I would accept that comment as the solution if possible): [Font Rendering / Line-Height Issue on Mac/PC (outside of element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element) which outlines the same issue and contained the solution.

Sadly FontSquirrel was not an option as it blocks Adobe fonts. But I edited the font using FontForge as mentioned in the post by Luke: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508202/1084239

For me none of the checkboxes were checked but the "Win ..." metrics were different than the other metrics. I copied the "Win Ascent" and "Win Descent" values into the corresponding "Typo" and "HHead" fields as my issue was that mac displayed the font incorrectly (and left all the checkboxes unchecked). After exporting the font as ttf using the default settings and ignoring any warnings, it generated a font that finally worked correctly on both mac and windows.