# How can I compensate for fonts rendering differently on windows on a web page

Tags: css, fonts, operating-system

I have a web page with text and an image. I want to place the text very precisely over the image.

I have discovered that with the font I am using, when viewing the page on windows, everything gets shifted down by about 4px. On Mac, iphone and android, it is placed correctly.

This does not happen if I use Courier New as the font, so I know that the problem is the font, however I have no choice but to use this font.

Is there a way to compensate for this purely in CSS, or do I need a javascript callback to detect windows and add a class so I can deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I would try tuning ling height, if that did not work, then I think you need to edit the font itself, you can do that using this site: https://transfonter.org/, uploading your font file and convert it to the formats you use and the important point is to check this toggle button, it adjusts some properties in the font so it has similar experience on different operating systems
[image: transfonter]

if that did not work, there is a program called [fontforge](https://fontforge.org/) it gives you the ability to change font metrics, for more info you could check this question
[Font Rendering / Line-Height Issue on Mac/PC (outside of element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element)