# Header text fix in safari

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, the following text works when I created it in my windows computer, but when we test run it the text stays the same in windows computer, but when the website opens in safari the text is cut of how do I fix this?

The mobile works fine, it's just the desktop.

Here is the CSS Code for the text:

```
.header{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    color: #006400;        
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 75%;
    font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif,cursive;
}
```

Tried checking the CSS but not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting overall- is that margin-right at 75% relevant to your final outcome? If you could provide a runnable example I think it would help us help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and perhaps a picture of the problem in Safari so we can see what 'cut off' means.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're missing line-height in that CSS block, try defining that first.
If that doesn't work, I recommend looking at this thread, there are a bunch of different solutions here. [Font Rendering / Line-Height Issue on Mac/PC (outside of element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element)